# how to save the pivot table result into an new excel using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Please find the full source code is shown below:

```
msft = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\xyz_ ___week_05.csv")
msft.to_excel("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\xyz_ ___week_05.xlsx")
msft = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\xyz_ ___week_05.xlsx",skiprows=[0])
msft.to_excel("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\xyz_ ___week_05.xlsx")
msft['Tested On'] = pd.to_datetime(msft['Tested On'])
msft['Tested On'].dt.date
df = msft[msft['Tested On'] == '2018-02-02']
pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Run'], columns = 'Status', aggfunc = 'count')
df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\week_05.xlsx")
df.head()
```

`

**Expected result:**
In this, i need to filter by date field, and with that result i need to create a  new excel.

**Actual result:**
While using the above code, I get an empty table.

Comment: Well do you know if the pivot has anything in it? Also you're not saving the pivot into any variable so you can do `df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Run'], columns = 'Status', aggfunc = 'count')`

Comment: @Orenshi I tried with saving a pivot in a variable, but though it reports only the empty table. Maybe in this line, do i need to change `df = msft[msft['Tested On'] == '2018-02-02']`

Comment: @Orenshi: Yes, founded it out because of this line only, I couldn't able to get the perfect result `df = msft[msft['Tested On'] == '2018-02-02']`  Please help me to rewrite that code.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: `<tb>Plan Run Status Tested On
P0 P0 Passed 11/02/2018  8:42AM
P1 P2 Failed 02/02/2018  8:42AM
- Canary Passed 11/02/2018  8:42AM
- Sanity Blocked 01/02/2018  8:42AM
</tb>`

Comment: @Ben Sorry I don't how to create table. But please help me to find answer for this?